# Ontology Management Program supporting Weighted Relations between nodes

Tags: ontology, relation, protege, weighted

I am looking for ontology management services which can handle "bi-relation"

for example, suppose that there are nodes "Tiger" and "Lion"

We want to describe quantitive relation between the nodes : 
i.e) Similar("Tiger", "Lion") = 0.5

I have searched Protege ontology system. 
However, the ontology system does not support this kind of weighted relation

Are there any program which can support to describe this kind of relations?

Or there are some way to deal with these relations with Protege?

Answer (score 0):

There are no common tools for such tasks as far as I know.

I am currently developing a python module that computes a similarity measure between tags if you have a database of instances and an ontology. Comment underneath if you have specific requests.